# Can't close tabs on browsers using middle-click unless the browser has focus

Tags: macos, mouse

I have just recently acquired a Mac Pro 3.1 and have been a strictly Windows/Linux guy my whole life. But I'm really liking Mac and starting to get used to it.

I imagine that I'll be on this stackexchange a bit more in the near future, and so I had one basic question to get started.

Basically, as the title says, when my browser doesn't have focus e.g. chrome/safari in the background while using iMessage, I can't move my mouse over a tab and middle click to close a tab, which I was used to being able to do in windows. The middle click does work to close tabs when the browser has focus. Obviously, this is a very minor issue, and I was just wondering as to whether or not this is supposed to happen.

Another little issue is that I can't middle click and drag or middle click then move mouse to scroll on pages and I was wondering if there is another function for that or if it's my mouse (Asus Reign of Gaming mouse from my PC).

Any help/advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) I do not know the answers but I can tell you I had to get used to some new gestures after switching to Mac.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. Yeah, at this point, I think I'm just gonna have to adjust, but I'm going to leave this up in case I can find a work around because I always use this because I still have my windows laptop and that will make it a bit harder to break the habit, haha.

Comment: Just leave your question open. Someone might come around that knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid you're out of luck here. OSX never gives focus to a window unless you left-click on it or Cmd-Tab to it. There were some older solutions that could provide focus-follows-mouse, though they're not supported in the newest versions of OSX.

Sadly, middle-clicking non-focused Chrome tabs *used* to close them. But I believe this feature was lost once Mavericks came out. You can middle-click on some other apps (like Terminal), and they'll respond appropriately. But no browser seems to do so.

As for your question about using middle-click-and-drag to scroll, that's something I dearly miss from Windows, but I haven't found a free way to get it on Chrome in OSX (it works in Firefox, though). [Smart Scroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) is an app that offers "Vector Scroll", which works like the feature we want. But it costs $15.